# Python обработка списка со словарями через map, lambda

Tags: python, list, map, dict, lambda

Мое почтение. Задача такова:

**Имеем список словарей, надо из каждого словаря, получить значение по ключу и добавить в новый список(Который будет хранить, только эти значения). *Размер списка со словарями всегда известен.***

Через циклы по старинке проблем нет реализовать это дело. Но было бы интереснее реализовать через map, lambda или подобное.

Пример списка со словарями:

```
response_oi = [{
    'symbol': 'BTCUSDT',
    'sumOpenInterest': '109555.40300000',
    'sumOpenInterestValue': '2235729975.64190000',
    'timestamp': 1657847400000},
    ......... и т.д.
]
```

Обработать один словарь, ок, но как получить доступ к элементу словаря когда он не один через lambda или map уже голову "сломал".

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_dict = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]

result = list(map(lambda x : x.get('a'), list_dict))

print(result)
```

[Взято отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Comment: Премного благодарен! Перешел по ссылке, и удивился что мне она не попадала, хотя гуглил и на стек тоже заходил читал похожие темы.